# Yodlee - Login form has fieldInfoList

Tags: yodlee

for contentservice id 2444, which got a fieldInfoList contains two login fields, how should I pass them to the `jsonsdk/ItemManagement/addItemForContentService1` REST API? I tried to post them normal but I got an error.

Here is the loginform JSON for 2444

```
[
  {
    "valueIdentifier": "OP_LOGIN",
    "valueMask": "500766LOGIN_FIELD",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_LOGIN"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "maxlength": 10,
    "name": "OP_LOGIN",
    "displayName": "BMO Debit Card(Last 10 digit)",
    "isEditable": true,
    "isOptional": true,
    "isEscaped": false,
    "helpText": "114195",
    "isOptionalMFA": false,
    "isMFA": false
  },
  {
    "valueIdentifier": "OP_LOGIN1",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_LOGIN"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "maxlength": 16,
    "name": "OP_LOGIN1",
    "displayName": "BMO Credit Card(Enter 16 Digit)",
    "isEditable": true,
    "isOptional": true,
    "isEscaped": false,
    "helpText": "160219",
    "isOptionalMFA": false,
    "isMFA": false
  },
  {
    "valueIdentifier": "PASSWORD",
    "valueMask": "LOGIN_FIELD",
    "fieldType": {
      "typeName": "IF_PASSWORD"
    },
    "size": 20,
    "maxlength": 6,
    "name": "PASSWORD",
    "displayName": "Password",
    "isEditable": true,
    "isOptional": false,
    "isEscaped": false,
    "helpText": "114194",
    "isOptionalMFA": false,
    "isMFA": false
  }
]
```

Cheers,
Patrick

Answer (score 1):

This login form has optional fields , you can show this login form to a user as depicted [here](https://developer.yodlee.com/Indy_FinApp/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Aggregation_REST_API_Reference/getLoginFormForContentService/Sample_JSON_Responses_for_Different_Login_Forms#Login_form_with_optional_fields)
  and then based on the response from user, you can only pass back the fields which are filled by the user and that request will look similar to the normal login form.